# Modify message format with template for non file destination

Tags: syslog-ng

With syslog-ng (v3.3) configuration how do I modify the message format with templates for non file destination. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
destination d_syslog_to_agent {
    syslog( host.name.company.com transport("udp") port(12345) template("${ISODATE} ${TAGS} ${HOST} ${MESSAGE}\n"));
};
```

The reason I want to enable templating here is because I want to tag my messages with the help of the ${TAGS} macro. If there are other ways to tag then please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config you wrote should do the job.

If you would like to add tags to the log message, you can use the `set-tag()` rewrite rule.

For example:

```
source s_net8888
{
    network(
        ip("localhost")
        port(8888));
};

destination d_syslog_to_agent
{
    syslog(
        "localhost"
        transport("tcp")
        port(12345) 
        template("${ISODATE} ${TAGS} ${HOST} ${MESSAGE}\n"));
};

log
{
    source(s_net8888);
    rewrite 
    {
        set-tag(".mytags.test-TAG");
    };
    destination(d_syslog_to_agent);
};
```

Sending a log message to localhost:8888 will generate the following output on localhost:12345:

```
338 <38>1 2019-01-09T13:16:13+01:00 localhost prg00000 1234 - - 2019-01-09T13:16:13+01:00 .mytags.test-TAG,.source.s_net8888 localhost seq: 0000000000, thread: 0000, runid: 1547036173, stamp: 2019-01-09T13:16:13 PADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADDPADD
```

Comment: Rewrite rules works. Appreciate your help. However, for my version of syslog-ng i couldn't write the rewrite rule inline. I had to create an object for it and then reference it from the log object.